# How to get objects from list by data from map with condition and save to another map using Groovy

Tags: groovy

Looking for solution how to match objects from list with data from map with condition if object field starts with map values and save to another map with Groovy

i have map with some data

```
Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap()
    dataMap.put("d1", "DATA1")
    dataMap.put("d2", "DATA2")
    dataMap.put("d3", "DATA3")
```

and list of DataElement objects

```
    List<DataElement> elements = new ArrayList()

elements.add(new DataElement("TEXT1"))
elements.add(new DataElement("TEXT2"))
elements.add(new DataElement("DATA1_text1"))
elements.add(new DataElement("DATA2_text2"))

class DataElement {
            public field;
    public DataElement(String text){
        this.field = text
    }

    public getField(){
        return this.field
    }
```

And i'am trying to get new Map where keys are values from first map and values are objects(field) from List with condition if object field starts with map value: Result should be:

```
[d1=DATA1_text1, d2=DATA2_text2]
```

My code is working but may be there is more elegant variant with using collectEntries:

```
    list = new HashMap()

mapping = dataMap.each { key, v ->
    elements.each { el ->
        if (el.getField().startsWith(v)) {
            list.put(key, el)
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataMap.collectEntries{k,v-> 
    [k,elements.find{e-> e.getField().startsWith(v)} ]
}.findAll{k,v-> v} //to keep only non empty values
```